# cffi.api.CDefError: parse error Python

Tags: python-3.x, rust, python-cffi, cffi

Using cffi, I'm trying to call some Rust function in Python code.
Here is the python code:

```
from cffi import FFI

def rust(solution):
    ffi = FFI()
    lib = ffi.dlopen("./libnorm.so")
    ffi.cdef('float norm(float**)')

    return lib.norm(solution)

solution = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6]]
print(rust(solution))
```

and this is the rust code:

```
#! [crate_type = "dylib"]

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn norm(array: Vec< Vec<f64>>) -> f64 {
    return array.len() as f64
}
```

I compiled the lib with:

```
rustc --crate-type=dylib norm.rs
```

But when I run my python script, I get this stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/cparser.py", line 260, in _parse
    ast = _get_parser().parse(csource)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pycparser/c_parser.py", line 151, in parse
    debug=debuglevel)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pycparser/ply/yacc.py", line 331, in parse
    return self.parseopt_notrack(input, lexer, debug, tracking, tokenfunc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pycparser/ply/yacc.py", line 1181, in parseopt_notrack
    tok = call_errorfunc(self.errorfunc, errtoken, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pycparser/ply/yacc.py", line 193, in call_errorfunc
    r = errorfunc(token)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pycparser/c_parser.py", line 1723, in p_error
    self._parse_error('At end of input', self.clex.filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pycparser/plyparser.py", line 55, in _parse_error
    raise ParseError("%s: %s" % (coord, msg))
pycparser.plyparser.ParseError: : At end of input

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(rust(solution))
  File "main.py", line 28, in rust
    ffi.cdef('float norm(float**)')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 105, in cdef
    self._cdef(csource, override=override, packed=packed)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 119, in _cdef
    self._parser.parse(csource, override=override, **options)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/cparser.py", line 299, in parse
    self._internal_parse(csource)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/cparser.py", line 304, in _internal_parse
    ast, macros, csource = self._parse(csource)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/cparser.py", line 262, in _parse
    self.convert_pycparser_error(e, csource)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/cparser.py", line 291, in convert_pycparser_error
    raise api.CDefError(msg)
cffi.api.CDefError: parse error
: At end of input
```

Am I missing something?

I tried several version for: `ffi.cdef('float norm(float**)')`. Like `ffi.cdef('float norm(Vec< Vec<float>>)')` or `ffi.cdef('float norm(float[][])')`
But it doesn't work too.

Thanks for future replying.

Comment: You cannot put `Vec` in a FFI signature. Please read the [FFI Omnibus](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/). Many people make this mistake, so I'd really appreciate it if you could tell me any sources that say you can do this or any thought process you had that led to writing this code. Then maybe the Rust community can start to fix the problem at the source.

Comment: I didn't see this documentation, so I tought it was possible.
I need to change my code and my way to think. Thanks

Comment: To answer your original question (even though it won't work because of ``Vec``): you are missing a semicolon at the end of the function declaration inside the ``cdef("xxx")``.